# "this" in an arrow function, in node.js middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, middleware, arrow-functions

I am reading a node.js book that is a couple of years old. There is an example that it creates a middleware from scratch, to add messages to a session variable.

This is the code from the book, the middleware

```
const express = require('express');
const res = express.response;

res.message = function(msg, type){
  type = type || 'info';
  var sess = this.req.session;
  sess.messages = sess.messages || [];
  sess.messages.push({ type: type, string: msg });
};
```

I guess the `this` here reffers to the `res.message`?  If I console log the `this` from the function, then I get a huge `ServerResponse` like this :

```
 ServerResponse {
  domain: null,
  _events: { finish: [Function: bound resOnFinish] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  output: [],
  outputEncodings: [],
  outputCallbacks: [],
a lot more lines...
```

If I try to convert it to an anonymous arrow function, like so

```
res.message = (msg, type)=>{
  type = type || 'info';
  var sess = this.req.session;
  sess.messages = sess.messages || [];
  sess.messages.push({ type: type, string: msg });
};
```

then I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined`

Since the `this` is lexically bound in arrow functions, maybe I dont need the `this` at all

```
res.message = (msg, type)=>{
  type = type || 'info';
  var sess = res.req.session;
  sess.messages = sess.messages || [];
  sess.messages.push({ type: type, string: msg });
};
```

and again I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined`. If I console log the `res` inside the function, I get a different `ServerResponse` like this

```
ServerResponse {
  status: [Function: status],
  links: [Function],
  send: [Function: send],
  json: [Function: json],
a lot more lines
```

So , how can I convert the function, to an anonymous arrow function? And what's with the `this`? Where does it point to?

(the book is "Node.js in Action" by Mike Cantelon, Marc Harter, T.J. Holowaychuk and Nathan Rajlich, ©2014 by Manning Publications, chapter 9.1.2)

Thanks

Comment: No, the `this` inside of `res.message` refers to `res`. The `message` is the function itself, not the calling context of the function.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Cool. So, why the `var sess = res.req.session;` in my arrow function does not work? Isn't the `res` available in the arrow function?

Comment: Inside of that particular block, it's unknown what `res.message` refers to, from what you posted - it'll depend on how the function is called (see the links listed above)

Comment: With `function(msg, type)` the  `this` refers to the instance of the current request on which you call `message` and not the `res` variable `const res = express.response;`, this `express.response` refers to a _template_ object used internally be express.  For `(msg, type)=>{` the `this` refers to the context in which the arrow function was created, and `res` is the `const res = express.response;`, but none of them is the current response. So if you want to create a custom utility function for a server response, then you need to use `function(msg, type)`

Comment: @CertainPerformance that's not true, because `message` won't be called on that `res` object. `express.response` is used by express as a _template_ object and is functions are then _applied_ to the current http response object.

Comment: @t.niese Thanks, I got it now. So, there is no way to have an arrow function that reffers to the current response ? I guess you can pass the current `res` in the function, like so, when you call it inside a route : `res.message('test',res); ` And the function itself becomes `res.message = (msg, res, type)=>{
  type = type || 'info';
  console.log(res);
  var sess = res.req.session;
  sess.messages = sess.messages || [];
  sess.messages.push({ type: type, string: msg });
};`. This works. But I am exploring other alternatives also.

Comment: Bindig the `this` is the purpose of the arrow function, so if you don’t want that behavior then don’t use the arrow function. What is the reason why you want to use the arrow function instead of the regular one?